# “Going” Vs. “If I go”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditional-constructions, subordinate-clauses

> - 1) **Going** to school everyday, I will feel bored and exhausted.
> - 2) **If I go** to school everyday, I will feel bored and exhausted.

Aren’t these sentences alike in meaning?

Comment: **every day**, not **everyday**, when the meaning is temporal. **everyday** as adjective means "common, normal, not unusual".

Comment: A good point. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are not the same. The first is a gerund phrase, and the second is a conditional.

The gerund phrase is used to express an *actual* situation, to say some activity *is* something or *has* some quality:

> **Walking** to the shop every day **takes longer**, but makes her feel happier and more relaxed than taking the bus.

The conditional is used to express some *hypothetical* situation, and its consequences if true:

> **If she walks** to the shop every day, **it will take longer**, but she will feel happier and more relaxed than if she takes the bus.

Answer (score 1):

With this clause:

> I will feel bored and exhausted.

you're predicting what will happen with a fairly strong degree of certainty.

Now the question is whether each of those **if**-clauses is idiomatic when yoked to the future, and if so, what their meaning would be.

> **Going to school every day**, I will feel bored and exhausted.

You are indicating that you *expect* to be going to school every day, even though you might not want to. You are referring to what it will be like for you.

> **If I go to school every day**, I will feel bored and exhausted.

You are indicating that you might not intend to go to school every day.  It is only a possibility. You may be considering the possibility. Perhaps you will make the sacrifice and undergo the boredom for practical reasons.

You could make that second meaning, that this is only a possibility, much clearer by saying:

> If I **went** to school every day, I **would feel** bored and exhausted.

The shift of tense to **went** and the modal **would** bring the *non-actual* to the foreground.

Comment: Definitely, your last sentence makes more sense than my sentence does.